# Was it common in ancient India for kings to take care of midgets?

Tags: india, ancient-india

The 13th century Hindu philosopher Vedanta Desikan, in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt2yb.jpg) from his work the Rahasyatraya Sara, describes how the god Vishnu in his incarnations pretends to be distressed out of playfulness and compassion:

> Therefore in the stories of the avataras or incarnations, the distress is only of the nature of play-acting and that, too, has compassion as its cause.  It is of the nature of lila or sport to the Omnipotent [Vishnu].  **Have we not seen hunchbacks and dwarfs often taken into protection by kings who do not expect any return from them?  It is a matter of lila or play to them and, at the same time, the consequence of compassion.**

My question is, how common was it in ancient India for kings to take care of midget?  The passage makes it sound that kings would do it in playfulness, perhaps in their free time when they didn't have to worry about royal duties.

Are there any other ancient Indian sources that describe kings taking care of midgets?

Comment: This wasn't India of course, but I understand it was fairly common in Europe for such people to employed as [Court Fools (Jesters)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jester#History). One notable example is [Jeffrey Hudson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Hudson), who I'd daresay lived a life interesting enough to hold his own in a conversation with Tyrion Lannister.

Comment: @T.E.D. If the same practice was there in India, that might explain why the passage describes the taking in of midgets as a game or sport.

Comment: I believe that a more appropriate term would be little, or shorter, people - not "midgets".

Comment: Caveat: [A midget is different from a dwarf because a midget will have normal bodily proportions. It is also quite important to point out that the term "midget" is considered offensive, so it is better to use the term "little person" to refer to a dwarf or a midget](http://www.enkivillage.com/difference-between-dwarf-and-midget.html).

Comment: @KenGraham I was under the opposite impression, namely that "little people" is an offensive term.  In any case, this is an English translation of a Sanskrit work.  I'm not sure what Sanskrit word is being translated as "dwarf" here.

Comment: AFAIK, in Russia before 18th Century people with defects were also taken to the courts of monarchs or aristocracy. And only some of them were jesters. I don't know to what degree it was due to the fun or to the compassion, but surely both reasons worked.

Comment: In Sanskrit  literature mostly in plays this character is generally called as"Vidushaka".Kalidada in his plays employed such a midgets as friends of the king ,a well wisher and normally as his messanger to lovers ir queens. I don't know about here. But if the such sources are valid and if you think this is somewhat related to what you are expecting , i will try to construct an answer.

Comment: And yes mostly they were having some kind of  physical deformities so as not to impress  his female companions.  :-D